# Setting up a PHP interpreter in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am a beginner in web development and am having trouble trying to figure out how to set up a CLI interpreter for PHP. I don't know what to do to set up an interpreter and the JetBrains tutorials seem to assume that I already have available interpreters.

I have previously used AWS to make websites, but I am switching to PHPStorm because my free trial has ended. From uses AWS, I did not need anything additional to run my PHP files, so now that I am using PHPStorm, I am confused by all these extra steps I need to run a PHP file. I am essentially confused with what an interpreter is, how to set it up, and how to view my webpage on my local server.

I also don't understand what the CLI is. I read it stands for Command Line Interpreter, but I don't know if that is any different than a regular interpreter.

I've read things like WAMP and XAMPP, but I don't know what they mean. I have Windows 10.

Comment: PHP can already run on the command line. You just need to install it. It's not really clear what your question is. P.s. WAMP and XAMPP are ready made tool stacks aimed at web developers

Comment: everytime I try to run my php file, it can't because it says it needs an interpreter. It gives me some options to resolve the issue, but when i follow the tutorials on them I get lost. I just don't know how to set up the interpreter

Comment: Show how you're trying to run it, and show exactly what errors and messages you get. It's hard to help just by guessing at the problem

Comment: ok so I have since gotten laragon and it is running without any error, but it is not opening in the webserver. It compiles the code in a new window in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 12):

To download & install the PHP Interpreter and use it in PHPStorm :

#### 1. Visual C++ Redistributable

1. **Make sure you've installed** *Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015-2019* : [x64](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x64.exe) or [x86](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/VC_redist.x86.exe)

#### 2. PHP Interpreter (CLI)

1. **Download the last version** of the *PHP interpreter* (current: 2020-Apr-14 / PHP 7.4.5) at https://windows.php.net/download
2. There you've to **choose** between *Non Thread Safe (NTS)* and *Thread Safe (TS)* versions.

   - If you are using PHP as FastCGI with IIS you should use the *Non-Thread Safe (NTS)* versions.
   - Otherwise proceed to download the *Thread Safe (TS)* version.
3. **Click the "Zip" link** that suit your processor architecture (x64 for 64bit, x86 for 32bit or lower).
4. After the downloading the file, **extract the .zip** archive in the directory of your choice (for example, in C:\php\)
5. **Open the directory** you just extracted, you will see bunch of directories (dev, ext, lib, ...), DLL files and executables. **Spot the php.exe**, that's our PHP interpreter :)

#### 3. Configure PHPStorm interpreter

1. In PHPStorm, go to "File" menu (Windows), then Settings (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S`).
2. Go to "Languages & Frameworks", then click on "PHP".
3. Click the `...` button from the "CLI Interpret" field.
4. Add a new interpreter by clicking the `+` button.
5. Here, provide the PHP Executable path to the php.exe we've spotted earlier (eg.: C:\php\%currentPhpVersionDir%\php.exe).

   If done correctly, PHPStorm will display the PHP version & the path to the configuration file (php.ini).

That's all for linking PHPStorm to a PHP interpreter in itself.

Comment: Ok but OP said they want CLI version not a webserver

Comment: @ADyson **1)** The link to PHP downloads is in the answer's first sentence (although I would say: it can be non thread safe version as well (running it here with IIS with no issues). **2)** If you install local all-in-one solution (e.g. WAMP/XAMPP/OpenServer or whatnot), it will have obviously PHP with it, which you can also use as your PHP Interpreter in PhpStorm.

Comment: You right @LazyOne I've removed that point about TS/NTS versions.

Comment: @LazyOne sure but why is it ok to suggest to install a load of stuff the OP doesn't want? Just suggest the PHP install by itself, and show how to configure it with PhpStorm, that would be enough to answer the question

Comment: @ADyson I guess it's because OP have mentioned WAMP and XAMPP in his question in first place, so the answer here just mentions a bit what they do. I personally do not see anything super wrong with this answer. But sure, having more detailed answer on how to install an actual PHP on Windows is a thing to improve here (as OP seems to be completely newbe to the PHP world in general and may have issue with that as this stage).

Comment: I downloaded laragon and it has my php run, but it doesn't open it to a web server. It just builds it in a new window in PHPStorm. Is this now a matter of "connecting" PHPStorm with laragon to have it show in edge?

Comment: @titooooo27 in the original question you said you wanted a command line version, not a web version

Comment: I thought they accomplish the same thing. the whole cli and webserver thing is confusing me more and more

Comment: I've removed the web server suggestion and detailled how to download+install the PHP interpreter and configure it in PHPStorm only, Thx for your suggestion :).